# Cannot solve "A named connection string was used, but the name 'DefaultConnection' was not found in the application's configuration." error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am new to .NET Core 6, coming from .NET Framework.

I configured connection string in appsettings.json file, this way:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Plataforma;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;"
}
```

Then, I scaffolded from an existing database, this way:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection name=DefaultConnection 
        -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
        -OutputDir Models/DB -Force -NoPluralize
```

Database was scaffolded correctly. When I try to use it, I get this error:

> A named connection string was used, but the name 'DefaultConnection'
> was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named
> connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and
> a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application.

I saw that the Db context created has this method, in generated `Plataforma` class, which is derived from `DbContext`:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection");
        }
    }
```

When debugging, I saw that `IsConfigured` is false, so it calls `UseSqlServer` method and after that, `IsConfigured` becomes true.

By reading other posts here in S.O., I added this in Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Plataforma>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

However, when debugging, I saw that `IsConfigured` property is still false when called `OnConfiguring` method, so it tries to configure again using that named connection.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `DbContext` file should have the same name for the file itself and the class name. This name will be configured in the `ConnectionString` as well as in `Program.cs`.

The name of the DbContext in your case is `DefaultConnection` as you have specified it in the scaffold command `name=DefaultConnection`.

The registration of the DbContext in Program.cs file should use this same context name as the following:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DefaultConnection>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Refer to this [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#add-a-database-context-1) for more related details.

Comment: Yes, that is how I have and it did not work, but I have found a solution. the `builder.Services.AddDbContext` action have never been called. In order to make that call, I added the DbContext as a parameter for my custom user store constructor, this way: `public ExternalUserStore(ILogger<ExternalUserStore> logger, PlataformaContext db)`. That way, the connection string was correctly set up.

Comment: The answer suggests changing `builder.Services.AddDbContext<Plataforma>`  to `builder.Services.AddDbContext<**DefaultConnection**>`. Can you please confirm that it is not working with this change only?

Comment: Also, According to your comment, `Plataforma` becomes confusing now. Is it the name of the `DbContext`? where did you entered it? because in the question, the scaffolding command specifies context name as `DefaultConnection` like the following Scaffold-`DbContext -Connection name=DefaultConnection`

Comment: Database is called `Plataforma`. When scaffolding. the created context class was `PlataformaContext`. Sorry, but when I wrote the question, I missed to write the `Context` Suffix. The scaffolding command also added `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection");` in the `OnConfiguring` method of the `PlataformaContext` class. With this problem, I understood that the call to `services.AddDbContext` does not execute the action method until the dependency injection is acting. It acts when I pass the object as a constructor parameter. That way, the `AddDbContext` action was executed.